# Inserting data into multiple tables using Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I have two tables in my database that I am filling via Web API:

```
Orders
________
OrderID
OrderDate
OrderStatusID
```

and

```
OrderItems
___________
OrderID
ItemID
ItemVersionID
ItemNote
ItemSortOrder
```

I need to insert `Order` and all the items for that order in two tables. `OrderID` is an identity field generated by the database that I will need for inserting data into `OrderItems` table.

Primary key for the `OrderItems` table is a composite key `(OrderID, ItemID, ItemVersionID)`, it is important since the same order can contain multiple items with the same ID but different Version ID.

I was wondering if I will have to add `Order` and `OrderItems` data separately or can do so in a single controller function.

Below are my model classes:

```
 [Table("SN_Orders")]
    public class Order
    {
        [Key]
        public int OrderID { get; set; }
        public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
        public int OrderStatusID { get; set; }
        public List<OrderItem> Details { get; set; }
    }

    [Table("SN_OrderItems")]
    public class OrderItem
    {
        [Column(Order = 0), Key]
        public int ItemID { get; set; }
        [Column(Order = 1), Key]
        public int ItemVersionID { get; set; }
        [Column(Order = 2), Key]
        public int OrderID { get; set; }
        public string ItemNote { get; set; }
        public int ItemSortOrder { get; set; }
    }
```

And below is my attempt to pass in a list of `OrderItems` with `Order`  that did not work out:

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult PostItemToOrder(myClass.Order ord1, List<myClass.OrderItem> itemList)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }
    using (MyContext ctx = new MyContext())
    {
        ctx.Orders.Add(ord1);
        ctx.SaveChanges();

        foreach (var item in itemList)
        {
             item.OrderID=ord1.OrderId;
             ctx.OrderItems.Add(item);
             ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Is that something that is possible to accomplish at once? Or will I have to insert order first, return the `OrderID` to the calling program and then insert Items?

Answer (score 0):

Put it like this:

Your `Order` class should have:

```
public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // all rest

    public virtual ICollection<OrderItem> Items { get; set; } // here is the trick
}

[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult PostItemToOrder(myClass.Order ord1, List<myClass.OrderItem> itemList)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    using (MyContext ctx = new MyContext())
    {
        var order = ord1;
        order.Items = itemList;

        ctx.Orders.Add(order);
        ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast response! I have changed `public List<OrderItem> Details { get; set; }` to `public ICollection<OrderItem> Details { get; set; }` and modified the controller code per your suggestion but it still did not work. Could using `virtual` keyword make a difference in Order model declaration?

Comment: In your `OrderItem` class do you have `public virtual Order Order { get; set; }`? The above code should work without a problem. What is in the `List<myClass.OrderItem> itemList` list?

Comment: no, I do not have `public virtual Order Order { get; set; }` set

Comment: List<myClass.OrderItem> itemList is a list of objects of type myClass.OrderItem, something like: `
 var order_item = {
                    ItemID: 1,
                    ItemVersionID: 1,
                    ItemNote: "Test",
                    ItemSortOrder: 1
}`. Basically a list of objects like this one